An estimate on GRH for symmetric power L-function
I have a question in an article of K. Soundararajan and Matthew P. Young : The second moment of quadratic twists of
modular L-functions.
In their article, one says that using the GRH for $L\left(s, \operatorname{sym}^2 f\right)$ we may see that
$$
\sum_{p \leq y}\left(p^{-2 z_1}+p^{-2 z_2}\right) \lambda_f\left(p^2\right) \log p \ll \sqrt{y}(\log X y)^2,
$$
where $|z_1|$, $|z_2|\leq X$ and $0\leq \text{Re}(z_1),\text{Re}(z_2)\leq 1/\log X$  .
I search the result in ANT of Iwaniec and Kowalski, and know that on GRH for $L\left(s, \operatorname{sym}^2 f\right)$, we have that
$$
\sum_{p \leq y} \lambda_f\left(p^2\right) \log p \ll \sqrt{y}(\log  y)^2,
$$
and I try to use partial summation in the first formula, I get that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{p \leq y}\left(p^{-2 z_1}+p^{-2 z_2}\right) \lambda_f\left(p^2\right) \log p &\ll \int_{2}^{y}t^{-2z}d\sum_{p\leq t}\lambda_f\left(p^2\right) \log p \\&\ll y^{-2z}|\sum_{p\leq y}\lambda_f\left(p^2\right)\log p|+|z|\int_{2}^{y}\frac{|\sum_{p\leq t}\lambda_f\left(p^2\right)\log p|}{t^{2\text{Re}z+1}}dt \end{aligned}.
$$
However, when I estimate the second formula, I can only bound it to $|z|\sqrt y (\log y)^2$. If we have $|z|\ll \log X$, then I can get the formula I need, but in the article, we only have $|z|\leq X$, I don't know how to deal with it.
